# PackageNotFound for Finance Data Reader

Tags: finance

I installed LUBUNTU 18.04.5. LTS on my 16-year-old Intel Centrino laptop.
With conda 4.3.30 I got the error message below.
Please help me
Thanks.

==================================================================

(py3.4) ocjun@ocjun-LifeBook-C-Series:~$ conda install finance-datareader
Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

- finance-datareader

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-32
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-32
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-32
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-32
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch

(py3.4) ocjun@ocjun-LifeBook-C-Series:~$

Answer (score 0):

The package does not seem to be deployed as a conda package, but you should be able to install it using `pip install finance-datareader`.

Comment: ocjun@ocjun-LifeBook-C-Series:~$ pip install finance-datareader ........ This lxml version requires Python 2.7, 3.5 or later.

Comment: You might want to consider updating your python version in that case